# How can just one punch subdue an opponent with a machete?

Tags: punching, identification, entertainment

The screenshot beneath hails from [a brief fight](https://youtu.be/6_4-g8t-P6s?t=39) from the 2007 film [*Shake Hands with the Devil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shake_Hands_with_the_Devil_(2007_film)).

As you can see, [Maj  Brent Beardsley](https://www.thirdagebarrie.ca/bio/major-retired-brent-beardsley/) (portrayed by James Gallanders who uploaded this video) is about to punch the African with the machete.

1. I disbelieved this attack when I first saw it. Is it realistic for an unarmed man to punch someone with a machete who was standing in their way, in the context of the screenshot?
2. What kind of punch did Beardsley throw? If you watch the YouTube video, that one punch wholly overpowered the African that fell to the ground.

[image]

Note that [LGen (ret) the Hon. Roméo A. Dallaire](http://www.thesimonsfoundation.ca/peace-leaders/lgen-ret-hon-romeo-dallaire-oc-cmm-goc-msc-cd) approved it, but not [the 2004 movie *Hotel Rwanda*](https://www.huffingtonpost.ca/2011/12/29/romeo-dallaire-hotel-rwanda_n_1174607.html)

> But by movies, he sure doesn’t mean the Oscar-nominated "[Hotel Rwanda](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0395169/)."
>
> While he’s proud of both [the documentary](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0424435/) and **[Emmy-winning TV-movie] (imdb.com/title/tt0472562/)** based on "Shake Hands With The Devil" he is no fan of the most famous film to emerge from the carnage, despite inspiring the character in it played by Nick Nolte.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with martial arts whatsoever.

Comment: I do not understand why this question has been so poorly received. It's asking about movie realism, which has been accepted before.

Comment: @mattm First, there are two questions: one relates to hypothetical attacks against a target with a weapon. It is too board and since this is a movie utterly irrelevant for here. The second relates to what kind of punch is done: clearly a movie-powered hook. There is nothing special here. There is no link to the video, just a still image making identification of whatever the punch was harder. The rest of the post is about … Frankly, I have no idea of the point it is trying making. Lastly, there is point begging.

Comment: @Sardathrion The first link is the video, set to start just before the punch.

Comment: @mattm So it is. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I disbelieved this attack when I first saw it. Is it realistic for an unarmed man to punch someone with a machete who was standing in their way, in the context of the screenshot?

Holding, as opposed to using, a machete provides no protection to punches. There is no difference between punching the man with the machete who is standing and doing nothing from punching anyone else in the scene.

> What kind of punch did Beardsley throw? If you watch the YouTube video, that one punch wholly overpowered the African that fell to the ground.

I can only describe this as a bad movie punch. The distance appears wrong for the punch to land with any power, and from the screenshot the windup is needlessly large. I would call it a body hook. Do not assume anything about this punch is realistic.